# Proving that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{5^n}{n!} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, factorial

How does one prove this limit? 
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{5^n}{n!} = 0$$
L-Hospital would work, but only in an "intuitive" sense. (Or  at least, I don't see how L-Hospital would work.) I was considering $\delta$-$\epsilon$ as well, but finding a way to make, given $\epsilon > 0$, a $K(\epsilon) > 0$ such that $\forall n > K(\epsilon)$
$$\left|\dfrac{5^n}{n!}\right| < \epsilon$$
seemed to be rather difficult.

What would you suggest? Assume no further background than an introductory real analysis background (no farther than series of functions).

Comment: I was thinking about the Taylor expression of exponential

Comment: Does that even work, since we don't have series here?

Comment: For $n > 9$, write $$\frac{5^n}{n!} = \frac{5^9}{9!} \prod_{k=10}^n \frac{5}{k}.$$

Comment: For any $n\geq 10$, we have that $\frac{5}{n}\leq \frac{1}{2}$. Therefore
$$\frac{5^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}= \left(\frac{5^n}{n!}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{5}{n+1}\right)\leq \left(\frac{5^n}{n!}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
Thus, once $n\geq 10$, every term is at most half the size of the previous term. It is fairly easy to turn this into a $\delta$-$\epsilon$ proof.

Comment: @StevenTaschuk - Thank you! I had a feeling that such a question MUST have been asked before.

Comment: The stirling's approximation would be an other solution. But it would be cheating ;-)

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Rate_of_growth_and_approximations_for_large_n for asymptotic expressions for $n!$ for large $n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, so "no farther than series of functions" means we already have power and Taylor series, so

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{5^n}{n!}=e^5\implies\;\text{the series converges}\;\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{5^n}{n!}=0$$

Answer (score 3):

Then $\lim\limits_{n}\frac{5^n}{n!}\leq \lim\limits_n\frac{5^n}{10^n} =\lim\limits_n\left(\frac1{2}\right)^n = 0.$

which gives the required result by the sandwich theorem.

You just need to prove that $10^n < n!$ for all $n > N$ where you have to find $N$.

HINT: Use the representation $\frac{5^n}{n!}=\frac{5}{n}\frac{5}{n-1}\dots\frac{5}{1}$ and induction.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Let $a_n = \frac{5^n}{n!}$.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigg|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\Bigg|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{5^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{5^n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{5}{n+1}= 0 < 1$$